# Android Browser pauses when holding down anything

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, browser

So... i'm creating a small game, which is already working on my computer.
Now i want to port it to mobile devices. Well, everything runs fine, except when i want to use the right/left button which i implemented using divs with ontouchstart and ontouchend.
That's because the android browser pauses my javascript/canvas displaying while i'm holding down anything on the screen. When i release the buttons, my playerobject moves to the new location.

tl;dr: How can i disable the function of the android browser, which pauses my rendering while holding down anything on the screen?

Thanks in advance!

(Samsung G Note 2, Android 4.3)

Comment: The newest, 4.3... well, maybe it'll work after porting the game with phonegap?

Comment: Have you any `touchmove` handlers? Try to understand what's wrong by Chrome 32+ emulator and timeline. Chrome will emulate touch events and in timeline you can get info is needed javascript runs. If you want more help, please, add code example.

Comment: Ok, i'll post a link here when I'm home :)

Comment: If you want to just rightclick->view source, i put everything into one file (looks a bit clustered) www.indiearmory.com/jnr/mobile.html